# IntelliJ IDEA console seems to have extra "padding" between lines, causing background color to be taller than actual line height

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, console, themes, oh-my-zsh

I've installed Oh My Zsh with the Powerlevel10k theme. It looks fine in a regular terminal:

[image]

But in IntelliJ IDEA there appears to be some "padding" in console lines that cause the background colors to span taller than the height of the angle symbols:

[image]

I've tried overriding the default in Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font to set Line Spacing to 1.0:

[image]

In fact even setting this to 0.8 or less, while scrunching the text, doesn't seem to have any effect on the mismatched background color heights, leading me to believe it's not a problem with line spacing.

I know this is super minor and that's why I've lived with it for several months now, but it would make me very happy if someone knew how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue. Please vote for [IDEA-219163](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219163).

UPD: The issue has been fixed in 2020.3 IDE versions.

Comment: I know you already know, but for others, the issue has been fixed so update your IntelliJ. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239094

Comment: Updated. Thanks!